# Quarkus migration, rest endpoints test problem - TestInstantiationException because of IllegalArgumentException

Tags: quarkus

I am migrating application to quarkus. To current point with success. But I meet a problem which currently I can not bypass. I have rest endpoints and when I run app they are working perfectly. But when I am trying to use quarkus test framework to test them (@QuarkusTest) I am getting a bit nondescriptive error:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: TestInstanceFactory [io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension] failed to instantiate test class [com.daimler.pia.input.globus.resource.rest.impl.GreetingResourceTest]: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ConfigBuildSteps#generateConfigSources threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(ClassVisitor.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.gizmo.GizmoClassVisitor.<init>(GizmoClassVisitor.java:22)
    at io.quarkus.gizmo.ClassCreator.writeTo(ClassCreator.java:150)
    at io.quarkus.gizmo.ClassCreator.close(ClassCreator.java:203)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ConfigBuildSteps.generateConfigSources(ConfigBuildSteps.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:915)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:279)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2011)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1426)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
[...]
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.jaeger.deployment.JaegerProcessor#setupTracer threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[...]
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.logging.LoggingResourceProcessor#setupLoggingRuntimeInit threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[...]
```

basicly after each [error] stack trace is the same.

I found some cases on web describing problems with IllegalArgumentException and Quarkus, but usually there was some additional information.

I tried to move example from https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/master/getting-started-testing to my project, result was the same. Unfortunetly for time being I do not have time to deal with it. But eventually I will have to go back o that problem. Therefore I have decided to post here my problem becasue I propabbly am missing some small thing (or not) and maybe someone already solve that problem.

Comment: Could you share your code? Which version of Quarkus are you using?

Comment: Unforunetly I can not paste code, I can only paste the code from example which I tried to use in my project and which is coppied from here:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/master/getting-started-testing/src
Probably problem is with configuration or dependencies, but I was not able to determine which is the problem, or maybe both.